# ruby on rails undefined method 'username' in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, undefined

```
users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
        render_404
    end

    def show
        @user = User.where(:username => params[:username])

        render_404 if !@user
    end
end
```

basically i want to get each user data based on their username because later i want to include one more table which has meta-data for each user but i keep getting the following error

```
undefined method `username' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fb5dbc52ea0>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= @user.username %> profile page
```

Comment: `@user = User.where(:username => params[:username]).first` try this or `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])`

Comment: Which version of rails? Could you go to the console and attach the output of `User` to your question?

Comment: @mosch it's the latest one, error from console wasn't that different from browser other than 500 server error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@user = User.where(:username => params[:username]).first` try this or `@user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])`. `Where` returns `AR::Relation`, not an ActiveRecord object.